# Python requests-html render() has no href link URL

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I'd like to search on Paravi(https://www.paravi.jp/search) with a movie title and get a link to the movie. My current code is below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

title = 'invisible'
url = f'https://www.paravi.jp/search?q={title}'
session = HTMLSession()
res = session.get(url)
res.html.render(sleep=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.html.html, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

It contains something like this, but it doesn't contain an 'a' tag or href link.

```
<div aria-label='w-inds. LIVE TOUR 2017 "INVISIBLE"' class="sliderRefocus lockup" id="title-card-0-0" role="link" tabindex="0">
  <div class="ptrack-content" data-ui-tracking-context="">
    <div class="artwork" style='background-image: url("https://img.paravi.jp/files/88c22fdf228d4ee0baf33171fff70aba/95671030163.jpg?w=800&amp;h=800&amp;p=t");'></div>
    <div class="video-preload-title">
      <div class="video-preload-title-label">w-inds. LIVE TOUR 2017 "INVISIBLE"</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-wrapper hasTextArea">
  <h3 class="title-card-title">
    <p class="link">w-inds. LIVE TOUR 2017 "INVISIBLE"</p>
  </h3>
  <div class="synopsis">アルバム...</div>
</div>
```

I am new to javascript and html.
From where can I get the link?

Comment: it uses JavaScript and events to detect click and load another page. It may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to click in `H3` and it will redirect to page

Comment: it sends `title` to https://www.paravi.jp/anon/1/path?paths= ... (very long url) and server sends JSON data with numbers which JavaScript uses to load pages when you click `H3` - i.e https://www.paravi.jp/watch/82275 - If you could get JSON data then you would use these numbers to generate links to other pages.